Why initializing an UIImage or NSImage with ImageRessource is not a failable initializer?
This question covers UIImage as well as NSImage. Both types have some failable initializer, like this one:
init?(named name: String)

And this makes perfectly sense, since the resource could not be found in the bundle for some reasons. And in that case returning "nil" is a perfect solution.
But if I use the convenience initializer with type 'ImageResource', the initializer seems not to be failable:
UIImage(resource: ImageResource(name: "SomeName", bundle: .main))

So I have two questions:

Why is this initializer not failable ? (it would also be possible,
that the resource could not be found in the bundle)
What is returned by this initializer, technically it must be an UIImage (but with what kind of content)?


Good question for Apple.
